# Entity Framework - Creating an Entity that matches Stored Procedure output

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In Entity Framework 4, is there any easy way to create an Entity that matches the output of a stored procedure? I'm not talking about creating a complex type (which is easy), but creating an actual entity.

The reason I want an entity rather than a complex type is that RIA doesn't seem to auto-generate an interface for complex types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be necessary to generate a conceptual entity, then a store entity and a piece of corresponding mapping in the scenario you describe. In the other case the model will be invalid.